# How to use Realm List type with a given Model as a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, types, realm, protocols

I have the code:

```
   import RealmSwift
    
    protocol Cycle {
        var spokes: [Spoke] {get set}
    }
    
    protocol Spoke {
        var length: Int {get set}
    }
    
    class CycleImpl: Object, Cycle {
        @Persisted var spokes: [SpokeImpl] // List<Spoke>
    }

    class SpokeImpl: Object, Spoke {
        @Persisted var length: Int
    }
```

In my project, the datamodel schema is defined as swift protocols. How can I alter the protocol (without tightly coupling it to Realm types) or concrete type to have an implementation of this protocol without the compiler complaining that `[Spoke]` is not "persistable"?

Comment: `Spoke` is not a Realm object (it's a protocol) or one of the [supported object types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#supported-property-types); therefore it's not persistable. Realm can only store Realm objects or the supported ones. Perhaps there's something more to the question?

Comment: @Jay I added spokes implementation.

Comment: Ok. Good start but this`@Persisted var spokes: [SpokeImpl]` is an Array which is also not a Realm object and cannot be persisted. It would probably need to be a List object and defined like this `@Persisted var spokes = RealmSwift.List<SpokeImpl>()`. However, you then need to update the Cycle protocol to match. I would suggest dumping the protocols (for now) and stick with building the Realm models in the way that works. Also, going through the Realm [Getting Started Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/) may help provide clarity on working with Realm.